# Convert python array of int to SOAP ArrayofInt

Tags: python, web-services, soap, xsd, zeep

I am using the [zeep python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeep) so as to call a function through SOAP which accepts an argument of 'ArrayofInt' type.

Passing a 'normal' integer array doesn't work... the workaround is to run through the elements of the array with a for loop and send the elements one-by-one but this is not the cleanest code I have ever written:)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395599/create-a-string-array-parameter-with-zeep) will sort you out.

Use the Zeep's client.get_type function to create an empty Zeep ArrayOfInt object and then loop your array through it.

```
client = Client(soap_url)
test_list = [1,2,3,4]
emptyArrayPlaceholder = client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfInt')
options = emptyArrayPlaceholder()

for el in test_list:
    options['int'].append(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your method in SOAP service accept an array of integer as argument then you can try this way:

```
clientInt = Client(wsdl)
list_int=[1,2,3]
dict_int = {"ArrayOfInteger":{"integer":list_int}}
clientInt.service.getMultipleInt(**dict_int)
```

when you pass **dict_int as the argument, python3 will unpack the dictionary and pass the keyword in the dictionary as the function argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to retrieve object from wsdl try this:

```
client = Client(soap_url)
test_list = [1,2,3,4]
client.service.ServiceName({"foo": {"int": test_list}})
```