# SOAP(C# WCF) receive list of integer as argument via Zeep

Tags: python, c#, wcf, zeep

Here is my python script

```cs
request_data = {"request": {"PromoteRequestIds": [1, 2]}}
result = client.service.DeletePromoteRequests(**request_data)
```

In C# WCF.

```cs
public DeletePromoteRequestsResponse DeletePromoteRequests(
    DeletePromoteRequestsRequest request) 
{
    ...
}
```

The parameter object in WCF is defined as

```cs
[DataContract]
public class DeletePromoteRequestsRequest 
{
    
    [DataMember]
    public List<long> PromoteRequestIds { get; set; }
}
```

However, I don't understand why the `PromoteRequestIds` only contains one element `[1]` instead of `[1, 2]`.

Comment: You can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914102/convert-python-array-of-int-to-soap-arrayofint

Comment: Thanks, fixed my issue. Would you like to make an answer? @TheobaldDu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question, I found a reference that may be useful to you:[Convert python array of int to SOAP ArrayofInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914102/convert-python-array-of-int-to-soap-arrayofint).